# Trying to send data to Google Analytics with Measurement Protocol

Tags: python, http, post, google-analytics

So, I'm trying to send data to GA using their Measurement Protocol with Python.  From what I can gather, I will be sending POST requests via HTTP, but I'm not sure where to start.  The data will likely be coming from an API or Database.

My project is inspired by this video if it gives you a better idea: http://www.elisa-dbi.co.uk/blog/tracking-wemo-switch-motion-google-universal-analytics/

I guess I'm creating a wrapper, but I'm unclear to what exactly that is.  Any advice or input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can ask the one from the video, he will be happy, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can go throught the following documentation to send HTTP POST requests to google analytics 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

Answer (score 2):

By now you have probably already created your wrapper, but for what its worth, my firm has recently released a library under BSD license, with an API similar to that of Google's `analytics.js`.

https://github.com/analytics-pros/universal-analytics-python